Azure Data Factory pipeline save SQL stored procedure first row result value (JSON string) to blob storage
I'm using a stored procedure to query SQL database tables and the result is a JSON string.  I would like to store the string in an Azure storage blob but can't seem to figure out how to just store the SProc result value.
The stored blob data has the following... I just want the JSON value (red arrow part):

I can't seem to determine how to specify just the .value from the result set.  The preview data only includes the value.
I'm also trying to use values in a for each loop to specify the name of the blob.

In this case, instead of lookup or stored procedure activity, you can achieve your requirement by using a single copy activity.
Create a SQL table dataset without giving any table in the dataset and give this as source in the copy activity. In the dataset also, don't import any schema.

For the sink, create a delimited text dataset with below configurations. This will create JSON file in the target location.

Don't import any mapping in any datasets and in the copy activity mapping as well.
Now, run the pipeline and it will create the desired JSON file.

To use this JSON file further in ADF, you need to create a JSON dataset and use it as per your requirement.

I can't seem to figure out how to create the CSV dataset.
"For the sink, create a delimited text dataset with below configurations. This will create JSON file in the target location."
I can't find it in the create dataset list.

As you want to store the JSON in the BLOB storage, create an Blob storage linked service and create a new dataset of type Delimited text. Currently in ADF, it is not supported to create JSON file on the fly from JSON string. So, give the above settings in the Delimited text dataset which helps in creating new JSON file on the fly.

You can use Stored procedure option inside lookup activity to get the output of the SP.
To load the output result into a blob file in Azure blob storage, you can use a copy activity , point the source to a dummy file having a single column.
Now use additional column option in source setting in copy activity and use the expression @{activity('lookup1').output.value[0]}
Go to mapping tab, and import schema, remove the existing dummy column and only keep the additional column in schema and execute the copy activity


